# Is there web2py like admin in django

Tags: django, admin, web2py

Here is what I wanted to do. I want to load django in virtual host with mod_wsgi with all available django projects. Practically what I want is

I have all my django projects inside a directory say $HOME/mydjango. I will load all the directory listing into views as base url and each directory will be accessed as say something like localhost/{{django_app_name}}. I think I can overwrite the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE with directory settings and chdir in my views. But I am stuck at how to check which app is requested so that I can load module of that app for such request. I am newbie so any help is appreciated. I hope I am clear with my question.

It's not toally like web2py's admin but if someone know of similar thing, I will be happy if you point me towards that as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. A bit more limited yet serves the purpose pretty well.
http://sramana.in/web2py-instant-admin/